# Passing & returning a list/array as a parameter/ return type to a UDF in Redshift

Tags: user-defined-functions, amazon-redshift, udf, data-munging

I have a bunch of metrics that consume the entire list of float values of a column(think a series of order value on which I a doing some outlier analysis, hence needing the entire array of values) .

Can I pass the entire list as a parameter  ? It would be too much data munging, if I were to do this in python entirely. Thoughts ?

```
# Redshift UDF - the red part is invalid signature & needs a fill 
create function Median_absolute_deviation(y <Pass a list, but how? >,threshold float) 

--INPUTS: 
--a list of order values, -- a threshold
 RETURNS <return a list, but how? > 

STABLE 
AS $
    import numpy as np

    m = np.median(y)
    abs_dev = np.abs(y - m)
    left_mad = np.median(abs_dev[y<=m])
    right_mad = np.median(abs_dev[y>=m])
    y_mad = np.zeros(len(y))
    y_mad[y < m] = left_mad
    y_mad[y > m] = right_mad
    modified_z_score = 0.6745 * abs_dev / y_mad
    modified_z_score[y == m] = 0
    return modified_z_score > threshold

$LANGUAGE plpythonu
```

1. I can pass the `m = np.median(y)` from another function (using select statement on the DB) - but again calculating abs_dev & left_mad & right_mad needs the entire series.
2. Can I use `anyelement` data type here ? AWS Reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-data-types.html

This is what I tried . Also, I would like to return the value of that column if flag was "0" - but I guess I can do it on 2nd pass ?

```
create or replace function Median_absolute_deviation(y anyelement ,thresh int) 
--INPUTS: 
--a list of order values, -- a threshold
-- I tried both float &  anyelement return type, but same error
RETURNS float 

 --OUTPUT: 
 -- returns the value of order amount if not outlier, else returns 0

STABLE 
AS $$
    import numpy as np

    m = np.median(y)
    abs_dev = np.abs(y - m)
    left_mad = np.median(abs_dev[y<=m])
    right_mad = np.median(abs_dev[y>=m])
    y_mad = np.zeros(len(y))
    y_mad[y < m] = left_mad
    y_mad[y > m] = right_mad
    modified_z_score = 0.6745 * abs_dev / y_mad
    modified_z_score[y == m] = 0
    flag= 1 if (modified_z_score > thresh ) else 0

    return flag

$$LANGUAGE plpythonu
select Median_absolute_deviation(price,3)  from my_table where price >0 limit 5; 
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select Median_absolute_deviation(price,3)  from my_table where price >0 limit 5

ERROR: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
  code:      10000
  context:   UDF
  query:     47544645
  location:  udf_client.cpp:298
  process:   query6_41 [pid=24744]
  -----------------------------------------------

Execution time: 0.73s

1 statement failed.
```

My end goal is populating tableau views using these computations made via UDF's(the end goal) - so I need something that can interact with tableau and do computations on the fly using a function. **Suggestions ?**

Comment: Can't you use the built-in functions (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Math_functions.html) for it?

Comment: @Guy are you suggesting to use AWS built in functions inside this python function, instead of the python numpy functions(for median, std_dev etc)  - or just building out an aggregated function based on the sub-functions on the aggregated functions . Like , select abs(price-median(price)) as abs_dev from my_table  etc.

Comment: Redshift has quite a few powerful analytical function that you can use directly in your queries. UDF should be used to extend the built-in functions, and they will be slower, error prone and more complex.

Answer (score 5):

Redshift only supports scalar UDFs for the time being, which means that you basically CANNOT pass a list as a parameter.

That being said, you can be creative and pass it as a string of numbers separated with a special character and then reconvert it to a list in your udf eg.:
list = [1, 2, 3.5] can be passed as 
string_list = "1|2|3.5"

For this to work you need to pre-decide the precision of your numbers and the maximum size of your list, so as to define a varchar of the appropriate length.
It is not the best practice, but it will work.